# List files committed for a revision

Tags: svn

How do I list the file names/paths that are committed, using a revision number?

Comment: Are you talking about the person doing the commit?

Comment: doing a svn log | grep 'username', lists all my check-ins, I want to see the file names along with the revisions.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

```
svn log --verbose -r 42
```

Comment: This lists files for that particular revision, adding username instead of revision lists all files and revisions for the user                                   svn log --verbose --username 'username'

Comment: "adding username instead of revision lists all files and revisions for the user" No, it doesn't. The `--username` option is for authentication, not to filter the listed revisions.

Answer (score 49):

To just get the list of the changed files with the paths, use

```
svn diff --summarize -r<rev-of-commit>:<rev-of-commit - 1>
```

For example:

```
svn diff --summarize -r42:41
```

should result in something like

```
M       path/to/modifiedfile
A       path/to/newfile
```

Comment: Right the details I'm looking for.

Comment: This answer is preferable in that it only prints one line per file, and the paths are relative to the point of command execution; whereas svn log prints header lines and footer lines and the paths are relative to the root of the repository.

Answer (score 3):

From remote repo:

```
svn log -v -r 42 --stop-on-copy --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD http://repourl/projectname/
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice short hand for previous version is the **-c** option  .. e.g **-c r42** means the changes in revision 42 (saves on having to work out the 41 for 42...)

So say you want to find say the files involved in the last *100* commits by a particular user - *foo* - you could use this to list them -

```
svn log . | grep '| foo |' | head -100 | cut -d '|' -f 1 | while read rev;
   do echo $rev; svn diff --summarize -c $rev . ; done
```

Giving a result like this -

```
r77504
M       PathA/Data.xml
r77103
M       PathB/SubPathB/Home.xml
M       PathB/SubPathC/YaDa.xml
r76498
M       PathA/Data.xml
```